# vim-commentary clears line instead of commenting

Tags: vim

I have [vim-commentary](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary) installed through vim-plug (you can see my full dotfiles [here](https://github.com/jdloft/dotfiles) with my .vimrc [here](https://github.com/jdloft/dotfiles/blob/master/link/.vimrc)). When I use the `gcc` command and then hit the down key (a range selection) on any line, vim clears the lines and goes into insert mode instead of using the commentary plugin to comment out that specific line. It seems there is a conflict between a type of `cc` command and `gcc`. My .vimrc is [here](https://github.com/jdloft/dotfiles/blob/master/link/.vimrc) and running `:nmap gcc` returns:

`n  gcc           <Plug>CommentaryLine
n  gc            <Plug>Commentary`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I use the gcc command and then hit the down key (a range selection) on any line

Note that gcc accepts a count *before* it, [as shown in the documentation](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary/blob/master/doc/commentary.txt#L16). When I execute `gcc` and `<down>` here it just toggles the comment on the current line and moves the cursor to the next one.

I couldn't spot anything suspicious on your .vimrc; the problem is probably caused by an interaction with some of the other plugins you are using. You could try to follow the steps on described on [Vim-FAQ  2.5](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-2.5). Some relevant parts follows:

> 2.5. I have a "xyz" (some) problem with Vim. How do I determine it is a
>        problem with my setup or with Vim?  / Have I found a bug in Vim?
>
> First, you need to find out, whether the error is in the actual
>   runtime files or any plugin that is distributed with Vim or whether it
>   is a simple side effect of any configuration option from your .vimrc
>   or .gvimrc. So first, start vim like this:
>
> ```
> vim -u NONE -U NONE -N -i NONE
> ```
>
> this starts Vim in nocompatible mode (-N), without reading your
>   viminfo file (-i NONE), without reading any configuration file (-u
>   NONE for not reading .vimrc file and -U NONE for not reading a .gvimrc
>   file) or even plugin.
>
> If the error does not occur when starting Vim this way, then the
>   problem is either related to some plugin of yours or some setting in
>   one of your local setup files. You need to find out, what triggers the
>   error, you try starting Vim this way:
>
> ```
> vim -u NONE -U NONE -N
> ```
>
> If the error occurs, the problem is your .viminfo file. Simply delete
>   the viminfo file then. If the error does not occur, try:
>
> ```
> vim -u ~/.vimrc --noplugin -N -i NONE
> ```
>
> This will simply use your .vimrc as configuration file, but not load
>   any plugins. If the error occurs this time, the error is possibly
>   caused by some configuration option inside your .vimrc file. Depending
>   on the length of your vimrc file, it can be quite hard to trace the
>   origin within that file.
>
> The best way is to add :finish command in the middle of your .vimrc.
>   Then restart again using the same command line. If the error still
>   occurs, the bug must be caused because of a setting in the first half
>   of your .vimrc. If it doesn't happen, the problematic setting must be
>   in the second half of your .vimrc. So move the :finish command to the
>   middle of that half, of which you know that triggers the error and
>   move your way along, until you find the problematic option. If your
>   .vimrc is 350 lines long, you need at a maximum 9 tries to find the
>   offending line (in practise, this can often be further reduced, since
>   often lines depend on each other).
>
> If the problem does not occur, when only loading your .vimrc file, the
>   error must be caused by a plugin or another runtime file (indent
>   autoload or syntax script). Check the output of the :scriptnames
>   command to see what files have been loaded and for each one try to
>   disable each one by one and see which one triggers the bug. Often
>   files that are loaded by vim, have a simple configuration variable to
>   disable them, but you need to check inside each file separately.

Obviously you will have to adapt the procedure to always have the commentary plugin loaded; you can use `:scriptnames` to ensure that it is actually loaded (you should probably retain your plugin manager).

Comment: As it turns out it happened to be `timeoutlen=50`. I created http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3964/timeoutlen-breaks-leader-and-vim-commentary to answer why.